# How to use and cache same node modules for multiple react apps

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules, create-react-app

I've created a simple react app using `create-react-app`, and deployed it on a laravel server. Now, I need to create another React app for my admin dashboard. The problem is, if I had to create more react apps in future for different parts, the node modules will take much more storage. Is there such a way to use same node modules for all react apps, and build node modules separately to cache it and react apps can use them in production without every app coming up with their set of node modules folder?